# In matlab, how to calculate p-value of a gaussian profile fitting?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, matlab, fitting

I want to use curve fitting toolbox to fit gaussian line profile. After I fit it, I want to calculate the p-value of this profile.

But i could not find the way to calculate it. Could anyone recommend the appropriate algorithm? The data which contain the Gaussian line shape is the residual data, i.e. they are around zero, So the p-value I want to calculate is the Gaussian profile bias from zero.

Comment: Maybe the `regress` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) function is what you're looking for. It performs multiple linear regression and returns a stats array with a p-value for the fit.

Comment: Thank you @Tinu, and in this function [~,~,~,~,stat]=regress(y,X), the variable y is the original residual data that contain the gaussian line, and what is X, zeros?

Comment: Sorry, the p-value returned by the `regress` function is something different. I'm not sure what you like to achieve. If you like to analyse your residuals to check the gaussian error assumption in your model, you can have a look at things like a Tukey-Anscombe plot or a QQ-plot.

Comment: Actually, i want to calculate the p-value or significance level of this gaussian line profile, not just fitting it. Is there anyway?

Comment: It's best to click "edit" and then modify/update your question to explain that. People don't always read comments so clarifying the question itself is important. This will also bump your question back to the active queue which may increase the number of people who see it. Also from [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080) When you reply to a comment don't forget to use the `@` like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QihMt.png (notice the auto-complete feature)